# "Kproj.Forms.frmSwitch" cannot be the root of a XAML file because it was defined using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, wpf-controls

I am aware that there are other questions posted that appear to be the same issue but none of them fix my issue.

I'm new to WPF I'm trying to convert a program from WinForms to WPF. I have a main window, "Kproj.Forms.frmLogin", that inherits a base class, "Kproj.Forms.frmSwitch", that inherits the System.Windows.Window class. WhenI got the above issue, my initial XAML code was:

```
<Control:frmSwitch x:Class="Kproj.Forms.frmLogin"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Control="clr-namespace:Kproj.Forms"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="LOG IN" Height="309" Width="678">
    <Grid Height="271" Width="662">
        ... Content
    </Grid>
</Control:frmSwitch>
```

with these in the code-behinds:

```
namespace Kproj.Forms
    {
        public partial class frmLogin : frmSwitch
        {
        }
    }

namespace Kproj.Forms
    {
        public partial class frmSwitch : Window
        {
        }
    }
```

Upon further research, I found out that I needed to make frmSwitch into a base class with no XAML. Thus, I created frmSwitch2 in just general Class form that looks like this:

```
namespace Kproj.Forms
{
    public class frmSwitch2 : Window
    {
    }
}
```

I then adjusted the main window XAML accordingly:

```
<Control:frmSwitch2 x:Class="Kproj.Forms.frmLogin"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Control="clr-namespace:Kproj.Forms"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="LOG IN" Height="309" Width="678">
    <Grid Height="271" Width="662">
        ... Content
    </Grid>
</Control:frmSwitch2>
```

and the main window code-behind to:

```
namespace Kproj.Forms
    {
        public partial class frmLogin : frmSwitch
        {
        }
    }
```

Now, I lost the original error message, but I gained a message that states

```
"The name 'frmSwitch2' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:FITS.Forms'."
```

even though it suggests "frmSwitch2" when I type "Control:" in the main window XAML, so it knows it does exist in the namespace. Any suggestions?

***Disclaimer: I tried researching it as best as possible but all the posts I found on StackOverflow were this issue but all were fixed by converting from XAML\cs partial classes to solo code-behind full XAML-less class.***

Comment: In WPF, typically the mainwindow is just a shell, it simply contains grid regions that how other user controls.  Start with that re-arrange your main window to contain grid rows and columns as you want things to be laid out. Then create your other controls as you would want them to be separate from one another, e.g. UCTitle for titles, UCNav for navigation, UCStatus for status bar, UCMain for main region in Main window.  Then use containment instead of inheritance.. if you really need inheritance then you really need to study MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into what the inheritance actually wanted, I learned that the only purpose of the inheritance was for variables so I was able to make it work but just converting them to static global variables and accessing them directly. I ended up not needing the inheritance after all.

If anyone else, that ends up knowing more MVVM, does come across a fix for this issue, it would be nice to know it. Even though I no longer need it, it would be good learning.